# Watchdog doesn't load in Raspberry pi 2

Tags: watchdog

I have an raspberry py 2 running debian stretch and I have done all procedures to load watchdog, but I can't get module to work....it just doesn't show anything, even error!
I can see watchdog 'device', but I can't see any watchdog module loaded. I have the correct lines added to my /boot/config.txt, but still not working.

```
root@skyweather:~# modprobe bcm2709_wdog
modprobe: FATAL: Module bcm2709_wdog not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.41-v7+
root@skyweather:~# modprobe bcm2708_wdog
modprobe: FATAL: Module bcm2708_wdog not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.41-v7+
root@skyweather:~# modprobe bcm2708_wdt
modprobe: FATAL: Module bcm2708_wdt not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.41-v7+
root@skyweather:~# modprobe bcm2709_wdt
modprobe: FATAL: Module bcm2709_wdt not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.41-v7+
root@skyweather:~# ls -las /dev/watchdog
0 crw------- 1 root root 10, 130 May 26 22:05 /dev/watchdog
root@skyweather:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              573440  0
rfkill                 28672  2 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            32768  0
snd_pcm                98304  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69632  3 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
i2c_bcm2835            16384  8
fixed                  16384  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                16384  16
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               32768  1 ip_tables
ipv6                  434176  32
root@skyweather:~# bcm2835_wdt
-su: bcm2835_wdt: command not found
root@skyweather:~# modprobe bcm2835_wdt
root@skyweather:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              573440  0
rfkill                 28672  2 cfg80211
snd_bcm2835            32768  0
snd_pcm                98304  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    69632  3 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
i2c_bcm2835            16384  8
fixed                  16384  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                16384  16
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               32768  1 ip_tables
ipv6                  434176  32
root@skyweather:~# uname -a
Linux skyweather 4.14.41-v7+ #1113 SMP Thu May 17 16:29:48 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: is there anything in the logs?

Comment: This question has many problems. Firstly you have `4.14.41-v7+` which is am unsupported testing version. What are "all procedures to load watchdog"? I don't know why you think `modprobe bcm2709_wdog` will show anything.  I don't know about `Debian` but `watchdog` works perfectly on `Raspbian`.

Comment: please add result of `cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: root@SkyWeather:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"